# how to integrate ola cab api and get the amount to be paid for the cab

Tags: android

I am new to android and i want to integrate ola Cab api in my android app, in this i just want to know how to configure that first of all i need to know can we integrate Ola Cab api in android, after integrating it , i need to show the amount that the user has to pay in order to travel(i will give latitude and longitude) of the source and destination

For example if i give the lat and lng of source and destination place  i need to know the cost that user has to pay for the cab .

**Note** : if i am not clear you please let me know i shall explain it in details

Thank you all

Comment: I'd suggest you start by reading the documentation of the API.

Comment: Thanks, i had read the documentation but i did not get proper way to configure it ,that is why i come to this forum

Answer (score 1):

Hey you are on right track you can integrate ola api in your api on this link you have the full documentation for integration of api [Ola api documentation](https://developers.olacabs.com/)

Comment: Yes pankaj Yadav, I have to generate Bearer <access_token> in order to move further if i try to do it says that the site cant be reached(by making use of the OAuth Url we can get that access token but i cant do that), when i try to add the header that isa advised to me in the documentation and use the URl that is given it says that 
{
  "code": "invalid_access_token",
  "message": "Access token in not valid"
}